# PipedReader never ready() at end of stream

Tags: java, io, nonblocking, ready

I'm trying to write code that reads from a `Reader` in a non-blocking way, i.e. only calling `read()` after ensuring `ready()` returns `true`.

To test the code, I use the `PipedReader`/`PipedWriter` combo, and `ready()` works great, until I close the `PipedWriter`, which also marks the end of the stream on the side of `PipedReader`. However, although its `ready()` method will never again return `true`, `read()` instantly returns `-1` when called.

In this case, is there a **non-blocking way to figure out that a call to `read()` would not block**?

Here's an example that reproduces the issue.

```
package test;

import java.io.*;

public class Piper
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int sleepBetweenChars = 100;
        boolean throttle = true;
        Reader reader = new StringReader("abc");
        if (throttle)
            reader = throttle(sleepBetweenChars, reader);
        while (true)
        {
            if (reader.ready())
            {
                int c = reader.read();
                System.out.println("Read " + c);
                if (c == -1)
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not ready");
                Thread.sleep(sleepBetweenChars);
                if (!reader.ready())
                {
                    System.out.println("Still not ready, sleep some more");
                    Thread.sleep(20 * sleepBetweenChars);
                    if (!reader.ready())
                    {
                        int c = reader.read();
                        System.out.println("Still not ready, we read nonetheless: " + c);
                        if (c == -1)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static Reader throttle(final int sleepBetweenChars, final Reader in) throws IOException
    {
        final PipedWriter pw = new PipedWriter();
        PipedReader pr = new PipedReader(pw);
        (new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Start piping");
                int c;
                try
                {
                    while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
                    {
                        pw.write(c);
                        Thread.sleep(sleepBetweenChars);
                    }
                    pw.close();
                    System.out.println("Closed PipedWriter");
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        })).start();
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PipedReader never ready() at end of stream

I agree. That's not what it's for. `ready()` tells you whether there is *data* available to be read, not end-of-file conditions. See the Javadoc: ' A piped character stream is ready if the circular buffer is not empty'.

There isn't a way to do what you're trying to do. Streams and Readers are irredemiably blocking. Your code is basically just an elaborate way of implementing blocking yourself, with added latency and added bugs. It's pointless.

I would also question your use of piped readers and writers at all. They are singularly useless things, really only a proof-of-concept for `wait()` and `notify().` Possibly what you're really looking for is a `Queue.`

Comment: You are right, the PipedReader docs state "ready if buffer not empty". However `Reader.ready()` is documented as `Tells whether this stream is ready to be read. Returns: True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next read will block.` Given that last disclaimer of course means any reader could in fact weasel its way out and even always return `false`, making the `ready` method in fact useless. Btw I did say I was only using PipedReader for testing, but I guess I'm out of luck.

Comment: The ready() method *is* useless, and it is indeed legitimate for an implementation to always return false, just as it is legitimate for an implementation of available() to always return zero, and indeed many of them do.

Comment: That's pretty sad. ready() and available() look just like what the non-blocking doctor ordered. And it almost works, in the case of the PipedReader. I wonder how other Reader and Inputstream implementations fare. I'm not giving up though: There's a way to somewhat workaround the problem by updating a timestamp on every actual read, and if ready() is still false after more than `timestamp + timeout`, just call read() nonetheless. Of course it's a parameter you need to get right. Worst case: rare blocking.